# RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 16.04 under the Windows 10 "windows on linux" installation.

I cannot connect using `rabbitmqctl`. I used `su` to run as root and also tried to run it under my username with `sudo`, but everytime I run the command I get:

#### Diagnostic log

```
attempted to contact: ['rabbit@SJDEV-JWRIGHT3']

rabbit@SJDEV-JWRIGHT3:   
* connected to epmd (port 4369) on SJDEV-JWRIGHT3   
* epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672  
* TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed   
* suggestion: hostname mismatch?   
* suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?   
* suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-133@SJDEV-JWRIGHT3'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: iLmkDqwKzDZPxk8ynhqsVw==
```

I have uninstall and re-installed both Erlang and RabbitMQ. I changed the host names as suggested by someone else, and I still cannot figure out this problem.

I have rebooted the system, and when I tried to run `rabbitmq-server restart` and got:

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "SJDEV-[NODE]"
```

I am new to linux and have been digging in to this for a week and hit my breaking point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out the problem in a round about way.  I am running this version of Ubuntu on the Windows Subsystem for Linux application on my windows 10 machine.  My windows machine is already running rabbitmq and it happens to be on the same node as the node that I was trying to access using the rabbitmqctl.  So there must be a correlation between the Ubuntu and windows system that shows rabbitmq already running.  I may try this on a VM and see if I can get a clean break and try again.

Thanks.

Comment: This answer is vague and lacks any helpful detail as to what was wrong with your configuration and what you did to fix it. I'm left scratching my head.

Comment: I installed a vm of ubuntu instead of using the linux subsystem in windows. The vm allowed me to install rabbitmq as expected. Using the windows subsystem for linux rabbitmq could see my windows node. So i did a vm to separate it completely from windows

Comment: So you solved your problem by not doing whatever it was that gave you the problem? That seems like you did something else rather than solve your problem (and I still don't understand what the problem was).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today.

My config is below:

- Have a rabbitmq-server on Windows 10 OS
- Have a rabbitmq-server on Ubuntu which was installed on Windows 10 OS (Ubuntu 18.04 app from Windows store)

Now below error makes sense:

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "MyComputerNamehere"
```

Another hint was Windows OS firewall has allowed both of them, in other words, they are running on same computer with name (ex: MyComputerNamehere).

Though I know the issue, I didn't fix it by removing rabbitmq-server from Windows 10, as I wanted Windows 10 rabbitmq-server, so gave up on Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Hope this explanation helps someone.